# Rails combine member & collection in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collections, routes, member

I am trying to combine collection and member in the conversations path. But I could not figure it out,

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do

  member do
    post :reply
    post :restore
  end
end
```

and;

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
  collection do
    delete :empty_trash
  end
end
```

When I combine them it does not work, and obviously this one is wrong too!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `member` and `collection` in `resources` block. Like this,

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
  member do
    post :reply
    post :restore
  end
  collection do
    delete :empty_trash
  end
end
```

Or you may combine it like this also,

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
  post :reply, on: :member
  post :restore, on: :member
  delete :empty_trash, on: :collection
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] do
  member { 
    post :reply
    post :restore 
  }       
  collection {
     delete :empty_trash
  }   
end
```